# Convert an Int to an array of Ints indicating positions of bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, built-in

So if I had an int, say `0000100101101001`, it should be turned to an array like `{0,3,5,6,8,11}`. I am using a convoluted system using clz (count leading zeros) and bit masks to do it now, but something better should exist I suspect.

I'm on an i7 and using gcc, use of SIMD/SSE builtins considered a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this (should work for unsigned integers):

```
while (x) {
    /* Store rightmost 1-bit in your array. */
    arr[i++] = x & (-x);

    /* Turn off rightmost 1-bit. */
    x = x & (x - 1);
}
```

I suspect there are better ways to do it.

Comment: It sped up my calculation by 12%, excellent (that's half a day saved). I'm intrigued by your suspicion :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
void bit2arr(int *result, size_t len, unsigned val) {
  int count = 0;
  while (val && len) {
    // add bit to array if needed
    if (val & 1) {
      *result++ = count;
      --len; // Don't overflow output
    }

    // Increment counter regardless
    ++count;

    // remove bit and bitshift
    val &= (~0 ^ 1);
    val >>= 1;
  }
}
```

To take one bit at a time and save the position to an array if it's non-zero.

I used it with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const unsigned val = 2409;

int main() {
  int result[32];
  memset(result, 0, sizeof(result));

  bit2arr(result, 32, val);

  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    printf("%s%d", i ? ", " : "", result[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Which gave:

> 0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 0...

It should be easy enough to make the function return the size of the resultant array.

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t bit2arr(char *result, unsigned val) {
size_t pos, cnt;

for (pos=cnt=0; val; val >>=1, pos++) {
   if (val & 1) result [cnt++] = pos;
   }

return cnt; /* number of 1 bits := number of valid positions in result[] */
}
```

Comment: +1, I like the rolling of the bitshift into the loop condition